# Where can I find documentation for NHibernate ISession.Persist()?

Tags: nhibernate, isession

NHibernate's ISession exposes a method Persist() with two overloads. I cannot find documentation on this method anywhere. It's not even mentioned in the NHibernate reference material on http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html.

Is this method deprecated, or will it be? When is it supposed to be used? How does it compare to SaveOrUpdate()?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last comment on this thread http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1273 specifies it very well:

> persist() is well defined. It makes a
>   transient instance persistent.
>   However, it doesn't guarantee that the
>   identifier value will be assigned to
>   the persistent instance immediately,
>   the assignment might happen at flush
>   time. The spec doesn't say that, which
>   is the problem I have with persist().
>
> persist() also guarantees that it will
>   not execute an INSERT statement if it
>   is called outside of transaction
>   boundaries. This is useful in
>   long-running conversations with an
>   extended Session/persistence context.
>
> A method like persist() is required.
>
> save() does not guarantee the same, it
>   returns an identifier, and if an
>   INSERT has to be executed to get the
>   identifier (e.g. "identity" generator,
>   not "sequence"), this INSERT happens
>   immediately, no matter if you are
>   inside or outside of a transaction.
>   This is not good in a long-running
>   conversation with an extended
>   Session/persistence context.

Also it seems from what I could gather from other sources that an entity having cascade="persist" will cascade at the time of the call, not on flush. That might very useful too.

Comment: That is an excellent find. Thank you. I think I actually should be using SaveOrUpdate() instead of Persist().. but Persist() may indeed be useful in certain scenarios. Now if I can only figure out how to specify cascade=persist with FluentNHibernate.... thanks for your help!